# C++ - input a series of 1s and 0s. Then automatically assign to the corresponding position in a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop, position

I am writing a coin flip program and i want the user to input a series of numbers as below

1.input 2 numbers x and y as the number of rows and number of columns(Done)

2.input the initial state of the coins with 1(head) and 2(tail) like below:

```
1010
1111
0000
```

3.Taking the step 2's input and assign the 1s and 0s to the corresponding position in the 2D array as below

```
1(grid[0][0])0(grid[0][1])...
1(grid[1][0])1{grid[1][1])...
...
```

For 3, is it possible to do so? What i have done now is asking the user to input the numbers 1 by 1 as the below code shows.

```
for(int x=0;x<rows;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y<columns;y++)
    {
        cin >> grid[x][y];
    }
}
```

Is it possible to read the position of the 1s and 0s using function like "char.at()" or any other advise?

Comment: Yes, to answer your question precisely, yes it is "possible to do so".

Comment: you can enter whole lines and parse it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
int grid[10][10];
for (int x=0; x<10; ++x)
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin>>s;
    ///check for string correctness here
    for(int y=0; y<10;++y)
    {
        grid[x][y]=s[y]-'0';
    }
}
for (int x=0; x<10; ++x)
{
    for(int y=0; y<10;++y)
    {
        std::cout<<grid[x][y];
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

Basically you read x strings from input e use it then char by char.
You can also read just one string with length = x*y if you want.